# Help in Identifying the components in the below picture?

Tags: network, switchport

[image]

One of my friends send me this picture asking me whether I have any idea what the device on left of modem box, which is connected to two COM ports.

He thinks I am smart. I will break to him I am not, but I'm wondering whether somebody can help in identifying the components?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like just a connector block for DIN, probably for providing a clean connection for the outgoing cable to the COM ports you mentioned. You'll need to check what cables run through to be sure.